# what is the best way to find array indexes using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have the following array: `var arr = [0,-20, 19, 4, 5, 7, -33]` and I want to extract the index of this array for all values.

I have tried `indexOff()` but will return only one position from array, so what is the best way to extract array indexes.

Thank you !

Comment: You want to store the mapping of 'index - number' somewhere in memory? Or what do you want?

Comment: what? Do you want all the indexes of a given element or what?

Comment: array indexes are just from 0 to array.length-1

Comment: @Dylan Meeus just want to return another array with indexes of my array.

Comment: `arr.map((_, i) => i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.map(function(element,index){
return index;
})
```

//This will return you all indexes. Let me know if this is what you want.

```
var p =[]; 
   arr.filter(function(element, index){ 
    if(element<0){ 
      p.push(index); 
      return index 
    } 
  });
```

console.log(p) // to print an array of negative numbers;

Comment: something like, yes. And if I want to return only the index of negative numbers ?

Comment: var p =[];
arr.filter(function(element, index){
   if(element<0){
       p.push(index);
     return index
  }
})

here p will have indexes for negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get all the indices of a value in an array, try following code

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,9,8,7,6,3,1,3,3,3];

function myFunction(arr1, value) {
    var indexes =  new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { 

        if(arr1[i] == value) 
        {
            indexes.push(i);
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}

var vals = myFunction(arr, 3);

for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
    document.write(vals[i]+",");
```